# Symfony Sonata Listmapper

Tags: symfony

I have an objet 'competition' MANYTOMANY but when i want to filter with listmapper.
i have only two choice on advenced filter.
"is equal to" and "is not equal to".
I want to have a filter with "contains" !!!
for the search - thanks

---

```
  /**
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('country')
        ->add('contact')
        ->add('organisation')
        ->add('competition')
        ->add('descriptionlongnat', null, array('label' => 'Description national'))
        ->add('descriptionlongen', null, array('label' => 'Description english'))
        ->add('category')
        ->add('preservation', null, array('label' => 'Preservation method'))
        ->add('population', null, array('label' => 'Population target'))
        ->add('innovation')
        ->add('timeframe', null, array('label' => 'Comsumer timeframe'))
        ->add('component')
        ->add('created')
        ->add('updated')


    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom filter as explained here : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-0/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#callback

Comment: use @Sam's link, if you need custom search - override base method and write your logic.